# what is the difference between 0 - 5 % 2 and - 5 % 2 in Python

Tags: python-3.x

the Python documentation states:

> The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its second operand (or zero)

So, in Python,

```
>>> - 5 % 2 
>>> 1
```

But when I put a 0 in front of it,

```
>>> 0 - 5 % 2 
>>> - 1
```

is it because the minus sign is different when representing negative numbers or subtraction ? How to distinguish ?

Comment: In your second example the modulo will be done first. So your equation will become _0 - 1_, which will result in _-1_. If you would write _(0-5) % 2_ the result would be _1_.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you are seeing can be explained based on [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

```
- 5 % 2
```

Here the minus sign in front of 5 denotes negation, which has higher priority than the `%`, so this expression evaluates as:

```
(-5) % 2 = 1
```

The same applies to the second expression:

```
0 - 5 % 2
```

Here the minus sign between the 0 and 5 denotes subtraction, which has lower priority than the `%`, so this expression evaluates as:

```
0 - (5 % 2) = 0 - 1 = -1
```